# Animation works on iphone but not on ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm using this code to animate buttons to bounce with different delays:

```
- (void) animateWithDuration: (float) duration andObject: (UIButton *) buttonToAnimate{
buttonToAnimate.hidden = YES;

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self animateButton: buttonToAnimate];
});
}

- (void) animateButtons
{

[self animateWithDuration:0.3 andObject:self.photoAlbum];
[self animateWithDuration:0.7 andObject:self.camera];
[self animateWithDuration: 0.45 andObject:self.helpInfo];
}

- (void) animateButton: (UIButton *) button
{
button.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
button.hidden = NO;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/0.7 animations:^{
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.0 animations:^{
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.0 animations:^{
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }];
}];
}
```

It works perfectly on iphone, but on ipad (simulator) the buttons makes a little jump up to the left with about 20 points on the completion block. Then back 20 point on the second completion. Using option: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone (or any of the options) on the animation lessens the jump a tiny bit but you can still see it. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Is there a difference in the way the buttons look, or do they have a different size on iPad? If the buttons have an image that is not in the exact center of the button view, scaling them might produce this side effect..

Comment: @Jesper Schläger - you are correct. I would like to add that scale will also be variant as screen size is different.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a background image on the button and the sizes are bigger on the iPad. Reducing the size of the buttons to the same sizes as on the iPhone does'nt seem to solve it....